# Add New Branch missing from Visual Studio Devops Work Items

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

We migrated from Jira to Azure Devops for easier integration for our workflow, and have been managing work items assigned to our team from within Visual Studio.

Once connected to our organisation, developers could open the Team Explorer -> Work Items tab and right click an item to create a branch to start the ticket.

This option has now disappeared from all machines, including mine (I'm the organisation global admin on Azure AD).

As seen:

[image: Azure Work Items]

Previously this menu had a "Add Branch" option which is the *only* way to create a new branch for a ticket without going through a labourious git sync workflow.

Is there a way to configure which options appear on this menu, or get them all back?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio do you use?

Comment: @AndyLi-MSFT VS 2019, upgraded to 16.3.5 earlier on today thinking that would fix it (it didn't)

Comment: Actually, I just test on an earlier version of VS 2019 and it works for me, for now it's upgrading to the latest version (16.3.5 ), after completing it, I will check if that works. Can you reproduce this issue on other machines (I mean a clean machine with VS 2019 installed)? In addition, please try reconnecting to your Azure DevOps account, open a version control solution, then check if that works.

Comment: I've reproduced it on two different laptops which it previously worked on, no fresh install though. I've reconnected TFS a couple of times, both to the repo and then the project to see if it makes a difference which it didn't. What steps should I take?

Comment: @AndyLi-MSFT strangely, opening Visual Studio and clicking "Continue without code" reconnected my DevOps account automatically and the option reappeared to create branches off work items. Not sure if I did something to trigger that change but it seems to be working.

Comment: Yes, that's I mean reconnecting from Visual Studio. BTW it also working for me with the latest 16.3.5.

Comment: @AndyLi-MSFT thanks, that makes perfect sense. Could you write it up as an answer and I'll accept it? Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally reconnecting your Azure DevOps account from Visual Studio will solve the issue.

For example, just open up Visual Studio, connect to DevOps, and clone a project, it opens the folder view. You can then switch to solution view. If you go through that process, you can right-click and have the missing options for work items appear.

Or just reconnect your ADO account, then open a version control solution from Team Explorer or just click "Continue without code".